# Не получается прочесть RAW запроса

Tags: node.js, express

Казалось бы вопрос заезженный, но в Express 4 у меня это сделать никак не получается. Мне нужно получить `raw POST` запроса и с помощью `crypt` зашифровать его. Как я это пытался сделать:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

function calculateSignature(key) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        var hash = req.header("TrialPay-HMAC-MD5"),
            hmac = crypto.createHmac("md5", key);

        req.on("data", function(data) {
            console.log("Data is: ", data);
            hmac.update(data);
        });

        req.on("end", function() {
            console.log("Called end");
            var crypted = hmac.digest("hex");

            if(crypted === hash) {
                // Valid request
                return res.send("Success!", { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
            } else {
                // Invalid request
                return res.send("Invalid TrialPay hash", { "Content-Type": "text/plain" }, 403);
            }
        });

        req.on("error", function(err) {
            return next(err);
        });
    }
}

app.post("/trialpay", calculateSignature("[MY MERCHANT KEY]"));
```

Итог:
- Вечное ожидание ответа, в консоли ничего.
Как же получить аналог `file_get_contents("php://input");` в Express.JS?

Comment: Может проще воспользоваться готовым [`bodyParser.raw()`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserrawoptions)? В нём даже есть опция `verify`.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, я инициализирую модуль, например `app.use(bodyParser.raw())`, а как потом получить этот raw из запроса? `req.body.toString()` или как?

Comment: Прочитайте документацию. Там всё написано.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, насколько я понял, этот `middleware` полностью заменяет `req.body`. А мне потом его спарсить нужно. Я попробовал в начале скрипта использовать его с помощью `app.use(bodyParser.raw());`, но ничего, абсолютно не изменилось, как был тип `req.body` `Object`, так и остался.

Comment: В дефолтном express.js `req.body` вообще нет. Видимо у вас уже есть какой-то middleware который его создаёт. Полагаю именно поэтому ваш код и не работает.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, есть и я это знаю. В корневом приложении инициализируются `bodyParser.json()` и `bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })`. Но мне лишь нужно получить raw запроса, а не во всем проекте получать вместо спарсенного `req.body` его исходник

Comment: Ну так `bodyParser.json()` уже выполнил примерно тот же код который вы написали. Конечно вы не можете прочитать уже прочитанные данные ещё раз. Ну, кстати, у `bodyParser.json` тоже есть опция `verify` и туда как раз в аргументах приходит raw body

Comment: @AlexeyTen, спасибо, это помогло! С помощью `verify` я прописал в `req.bodyRaw` сам Buffer. И потом все просто - `hmac.update(req.bodyRaw)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге пошел нестандартным путем. BodyParser предлагает такой параметр, как `verify`. С его помощью можно получить `Buffer` запроса и добавить его в `Express.Request`. Получилось примерно так:

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    crypto = require("crypto"),
    User = require("../../../models/User").User,
    bodyparser = require("body-parser");

    rootApp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded(({verify: (req, res, buf, encoding) => {
        req.bodyRaw = buf;
    }})));

function calculateSignature(key) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        var hash = req.header("TrialPay-HMAC-MD5"),
            hmac = crypto.createHmac("md5", key);

        console.log(req.bodyRaw);

        hmac.update(req.bodyRaw)

        var crypted = hmac.digest("hex");

        if(crypted === hash) {
            // Valid request
            User.findOne({
                _id: req.body.user_id
            }, function (err, data) {
                if (err || !data) return res.error(500, "Internal server error");
                data.deposit(req.body.amount / 100, false, "TrialPay Reward: "+req.body.oid, "offers", true);

                return res.send("1");
            });
        } else {
            // Invalid request
            return res.send("Invalid TrialPay hash", { "Content-Type": "text/plain" }, 403);
        }
    }
}

router.post("/", calculateSignature("[YOUR_KEY_HERE]"));
module.exports = router;
```

Спасибо за помощь и подсказки @AlexeyTen